Epoxy not curing fast enough -- Not enough hardener. Will it ever finish curing, or should I re-do
My first batch of epoxy cured fine, and then I had to mix an additional small amount to finish filling a hole. I think I must have gotten the ratio slightly off because the final layer is taking much longer to cure. Will it eventually finish curing? Or will it stay rubber forever?
It's supposed to be fully cured in 36 hours. After 36 hours, It's hard-ish, but can dent it with my fingernails.
Related to: The epoxy hardens extremely slowly - what's the cause? But I'm wondering if there's hope in waiting, or if I have to re-do. This is a non-structural application -- just filling up drill holes.
Product is: VViVid Scientific Water based epoxy - hard coating - optically clear. Mix ratio 2:1.

"It's supposed to be fully cured in 36 hours. After 36 hours, It's hard-ish, but can dent it with my fingernails." I couldn't shoehorn this into my Answer, which was already running a little longer than I'd initially intended. With an epoxy that has an extended curing time like this the variability window can be expected to commensurately large — with epoxies of more modest curing (e.g. fully hardened in, say, 8 hours) waiting an extra 12-24 hours can be enough. If we extend that by simple multiplication then you might want to try waiting an additional four days (eek). [contd]

If after 48 hours the mix is noticeably harder, like you can still mark it but there's really no dent per se, you're in line for at least an acceptable outcome. But it could well be that it will never achieve the peak hardness it would have otherwise.


Will it eventually finish curing?

We can't answer this for you. I don't believe anyone can definitively answer, even a chemist working for the relevant epoxy manufacturer due to the variables.
Whether an off-ratio epoxy will fully cure is down to the vagaries of the specific epoxy:

Some are very intolerant, as I'm sure many users of epoxy have discovered the hard way!

Some are more tolerant. The majority of consumer-level epoxies seem to fall into this category because the amounts are to be judged by eye and that means unquestionably some mixes will be off1.

Some are much more tolerant — one epoxy I've used, intended for a 1:1 ratio, can be mixed 3:1 and will still cure eventually (but of course not have the same properties).

And of course one of the main factors here would be how far off from 2:1 you accidentally ended up.


Since you can't discover what the actual mix ratio was, and don't (currently) know the tolerance of the epoxy, there's just no way to know if there's enough hardener in the mix to eventually kick the curing over enough.

But I'm wondering if there's hope in waiting

As a rule there's always hope if you're just a little off.
Time will tell — it'll either harden or it won't.
Keeping the item warm, or actively warming it up2, will not hurt your chances since the chemical reaction proceeds faster at higher temperature.
Localised heating, as with a hairdryer, or much more carefully with a heat gun, is acceptable.

1 Particularly when the two components are noticeably different in viscosity, and users just go by 'puddle' diameter, mixes can actually be way off — the thinner component will be a much shallower pool than the thick one. If you pay attention when watching YouTubers mix regular epoxies you'll spot this happening frequently :-)
2 Even periodically, the higher temperature does not need to be maintained to have a positive effect. Many, many times, and with a wide variety of epoxies (both liquid and paste/putty), I have heated the mixture up significantly just after completing work, and/or later on in the curing process, and seen a positive effect when compared to the 'control' — a puddle or blob kept to one side to check how hardening is proceeding. It is worth noting however that, as far as I can remember, the control always got to the same end point, eventually.


We can't answer this for you.

I think you just did. Partly my question stemmed from my own chemical misunderstanding of how epoxies actually work. I was partly wondering if the ingredient called the "hardener" acts like an accelerant. And I think the answer is no -- there is some optimal ratio to achieve strength. And my small batch is doomed I think.

I tried, as an experiment, to apply 100% hardener on the surface of my rubbery mess, to see if it could harden the first mm or so. But it's too late.

"And I think the answer is no -- there is some optimal ratio to achieve strength" Yes indeed. There is some wiggle room with certain epoxies, where the user can't tell the difference between say a half-dozen mixtures that are all slightly different (which is the case with individual mixes made from almost all basic consumer-level epoxies, sold in two tubes or a double syringe). But outside of any inherent wiggle room the mixture simply can't cure quite as hard, although it may still harden.

Re. the current rubberiness, out of curiosity how firm would you estimate it to be? Sort of akin to silicone rubber kitchen tools? Car tyre? Truck tyre?
